# Actionscript 3D how to develop 3d sprite

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, 3d, sprite

I am developing a flash application required me to have a rotational sprite object cycling around the 3D space. I saw a MovieClip has a z-index that can be used as z coordinates in 3d space but couldn't find it in sprite object.

How to I get around with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code on how to create a 3D scene in Flash with sprites:

http://memo.tv/starry_trails_3d_particle_system_actionscript_3_source_code

3D can get very complicated so it is best to play with an example.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "but couldn't find it in sprite object." what do you mean? Adobe's documentation of the Sprite class lists the z property in it's property list (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/Sprite.html). Perhaps you need to click "Show Inherited Public Properties" to see it? Anyway, the following pseudo-code might be helpful:

```
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(sprite);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

protected function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
{
    sprite.z += (mouseX - sprite.z) * 0.2;
}
```

Good luck!